# Need help get access to get remote_ip from a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi i got existing project within a model (let call at a) that call a model (let call at b) i need from the the last model a.k.a get the ip of the client the issue is i kinda bound with restrictions.

- the way the model beed add if from include mean it not for reall passed from controller
- one of the restrictions is make the few changes as possible

there for my question is simple let say i need get the ip not from the controller but from the model and it not save anywhere so what way i can get the ip.

p.s i did try request.remote_ip but it don't know request

if possible can u show me link or example code so i will understand how to do.

Comment: Do you mean you need the ip of the client who created the record?

Comment: What is the use case here? Do you want the actual client ip? Do you want to do it with the help of a controller ?

Comment: ip who request the route it self the models come from the feed so i need the remote_ip of who request this and sadly i cant rebuild for a lot of constraints
saidlly the part a.k.a model b dont event trigger from the controller more from model a via scope so i can't even pass the ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following for getting the remote ip of the client, this is using a controller.

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController
  def get_ip
    ip = request.remote_ip
    Test.use_ip(ip)
  end
end
```

Assuming you have a model. I'm assuming it as `Test`

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.use_ip(ip)
    puts ip
  end

end
```

As per your requirement, which is going against convention of Rails (which is not a very good practice)

define the following in application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :pass_request_around

def pass_request_around
  Thread.current[:request] = request
end
```

In model, request object should be available now

```
def get_ip
  request = Thread.current[:request]
  ip = request.remote_ip
end
```

Comment: thanks it good as temporary solution probably will rewrite bit later on many thanks